# How should I go about rendering an icon conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Problem Description:** I want to display an icon (from Semantic UI) next to a column name that has been clicked upon. A user would click this column to sort the list by that column.

Basically, I am working with a list of movies with columns - Title, Rating, Description, and Release Date. I have made 'Title' and 'Release Date' into clickable links which, upon clicking, sort the movie list by Title/Release Date.

My **routes.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'movies#index' 
           
    resources :movies 
end
```

In my **index.html.erb** file, I have made Title and Release Date as such:

```
<%= link_to "Title", movies_path(sort: "title") %>
<%= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(sort: "release_date") %>
```

In my **movies_controller.rb**, I am fetching all movie entries and sorting them with the help of `order` - `Movie.all.order(params[:sort])`.

All of this is working fine.

What I want to be able to do next is display an icon (`<i class="chevron up icon"></i>`) next to the column name which has been clicked upon.

My idea was to leave `<i class=""></i>` empty, and then set a variable inside ***movies_controller#index*** to `chevron up icon`, and then conditionally set it based upon `params[:sort]`, and then render it in the view. But I don't think this would be the right way to do it, because it wouldn't work for both Title and Release Date.

I am seeking the correct way to do this. Would I have use one of the helper files - ***application_helper.rb*** or ***movies_helper.rb***? Somebody please explain the logic to me. I am, as you should be able to tell by now, a beginner in Rails, so pardon me for my ignorance.

Comment: By "next to the column name which has been clicked upon." do you mean you want to highlight the current page?

Comment: @max I am sorry for the ambiguity in my question. I have now updated the question to include a screen for what I mean by "next to the column name"

Comment: This is typically something you would do on the front end in Javascript. While you could possibly do this server side if you REAAALLY wanted to its not going to make for a very good user experience. There are tons of javascript libraries to make sortable tables and even some gems that can be used if you need to tie it in with the Rails backend to fetch data dynamically.

Comment: @max Thanks for the reply. I don't think I am supposed to be using JavaScript. What I am doing now is part of an assignment at my University, and JS seems to be beyond the scope of what I am supposed to be doing. It makes me feel like I haven't described my question/problem well enough, maybe people are not able to fully understand what I am trying to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ERB you could solve this with:

```erb
<%= link_to movies_path(sort: "title") do  %>
  Title
  <% if params[:sort] == "title" %>
    <i class="chevron up icon"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to movies_path(sort: "release_date") do  %>
  Release Date
  <% if params[:sort] == "release_date" %>
    <i class="chevron up icon"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The `link_to` helper takes an optional block for the element contents which can be used instead of a string.

A cleaner solution though is to write a helper method:

```ruby
# app/helpers/movies_helper.rb
module MoviesHelper
  # Gives a link for columns in a table that can be used to sort the movies
  # will add an icon if the link is "active"
  # @param name String
  # @param column [Symbol|String]
  # @example
  #   sortable_link_to_movies("Critic rating", "critic_rating")
  # @return [ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer]
  #   <a href="/movies?sort=critic_rating>Critic rating</a>
  #   <a href="/movies?sort=critic_rating>Critic rating <i class="chevron up icon"></i></a>
  def sortable_link_to_movies(name, column, **opts)
    link_to movies_path(sort: "title", **opts) do
      # concat is needed to write to the text buffer of the helper
      concat name
      if column.to_s == params[:sort]
        concat tag.i class: "chevron up icon" 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```erb
<%= sortable_link_to_movies "Title", :title %>
<%= sortable_link_to_movies "Release Date", :release_date %>
```

This lets you test the method in isolation.

Comment: Why do we need to include that if-statement inside the 'do' block? Why do we need that 'do' block at all for link_to?